# C# Ftp Error (552) Exceeded storage allocation

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have this code for uploading images on my FTP Server:

```
FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://domain.com/" + "393174" + ".jpg");
                ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");

                ftp.KeepAlive = true;
                ftp.UseBinary = true;
                ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"location" + "393174" + ".jpg");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fs.Close();

                Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
                ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ftpstream.Close();
```

For some reason I get Error (552) Exceeded storage allocation: System.Net.WebException.

I tried with new ftp account on different location but same error. 
I checked FTP Quota is on Unlimited.

> The remote server returned an error: (552) Exceeded storage allocation
>   (for current directory or data set).    at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)    at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)    at
>   System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)    at
>   System.IO.Stream.Close()    at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()    at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream,
>   Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)    at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)    at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    at
>   WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in C:\Users\Demir\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 38

Comment: This might be helpful: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/ftp-says-quota-exceeded-even-though-the-account-has-unlimited-space-defined.388272/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much not enough space on the disk, this is the meaning of the error.

[Source](https://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10304.aspx)

> The 552 error code is coming directly from the remote FTP server. 
>   There is not enough disk space available to you on the remote FTP
>   server.  The most common cause for this error is that the limited disk
>   space allocated for your individual FTP account is already in use.

[Another article](http://www.serv-u.com/respcode.asp?resp=552)

> A 552 reply code may be sent in response to any command requiring the
>   server to store received information locally. It is a permanent
>   negative reply, which means the client is discouraged from sending the
>   command again since the server will respond with the same reply code.
>   It usually indicates that the logged in user has exceeded the storage
>   space allocated to their user account by the administrator.